My token appears as unknown and its data does not appear (token name)
I have created a token in Solana, but in Dexscreener and in the wallet it appears as unknown.
https://solscan.io/token/2Gr2tBomBKdp8tT5fesB8PRqKxs2HkapPQYJ9oTj1YtB
I have created liquidity at par with solana with radium.
https://dexscreener.com/solana/ho3jkhng5j2j3cctoyy8ncs5pz2urdkiyrs2cjjtoyx8
Please I need help before burning the liquidity,
How can I make the token name appear? the token appears as Unknown/SOL
only the Token image appears.
thank you

Solscan API has not yet indexed your token if you don't see it immediately.
Give it time and it will show up.
